# Trouble with Visual Studio --> Localhost --> Web Deployment Tool

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, iis, localhost

I am looking to deploy an ASP.NET MVC application using the Web Deployment Tool along the lines of [this post](http://discountaspnet.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!FC24ECAD565F3E2C!496.entry).  The way I've gotten that to work is by getting everything first working on localhost.  But there's one catch.  The way I've gotten things to run on local IIS is via the Visual Studio web tab, which requires setting up a Virtual Directory.  The catch with that is that I'll ultimately want to deploy the application to the root of my website.  I don't want to get involved with change path references like /Content.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.  Rather than running on localhost in the way I described, I simply needed to Publish to there.  noob mistake.